# jQuery problem with firefox, isn't it cross-browser compatiable?

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have problem here with this code below it works on all browsers except Firefox ,it's in external js file and the link in aspx file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var h = $(".img_cover").width() ;
    if ($.browser.msie) {
    $(".download_box").width(h + 1);
    $(".download_pdf").width(h + 1);
    $(".right_column").width(h);}
    else{
    $(".download_box").width(h - 22);
    $(".download_pdf").width(h - 22);  
    }
 });
```

Issue details:

- there is an image of a magazine and there is a download button below it
- those magazine images come in different sizes, so adjusting the width of the download 
  button below that image to match the width is necessary
  I wrote this jquery code to do this automatically..

**Testing:**

Local: works fine on all browsers

Web Server: (externally linked to ASPX master)

- Firefox: jquery code not initialized
- Explorer 6/7/8: works fine
- Opera: works fine

Code in the generated aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD MathML 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/mathml2.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">

<head id="ctl00_Header">
<title>Abstract and Applied Analysis — An Open Access Journal</title>
<link href="../../../styles/source_print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://beta.source/Scripts/lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




<script src="http://beta.source/Scripts/JQInt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




<link href="http://beta.source/styles/source.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/styles/xml_display.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://source/ArticleLinks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta content="source Publishing Corporation" name="Author" />
<meta content="Abstract and Applied Analysis is a mathematical journal devoted exclusively to the publication of high-quality research papers in the fields of abstract and applied analysis. Emphasis is placed on important developments in classical analysis, linear and nonlinear functional analysis, ordinary and partial differential equations, optimization theory, and control theory. Abstract and Applied Analysis supports the publication of original material involving the complete solution of significant problems in the above disciplines. Abstract and Applied Analysis also encourages the publication of timely and thorough survey articles on current trends in the theory and applications of analysis." name="Description" />
<link href="/journals/aaa/rss.xml" rel="alternate" title="Abstract and Applied Analysis latest articles" type="application/rss+xml" />
</head>

<body>

<form id="aspnetForm" action="../../../GetSpecialIssueArticles.aspx?journal=aaa&amp;pubYear=2006&amp;n=1" method="post" name="aspnetForm">
    <div>
        <input id="__VIEWSTATE" name="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden" value="/wEPDwULLTE0MDYzMzg1NjJkZFPSsoFb4eXsUpu+K/Hi3MXvMKWO" />
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="site_head">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="/">
                <img alt="source Logo" src="/images/source_Logo.jpg" style="border-width: 0px;" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="ctl00_SearchPanel" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_Button1')">
                <div class="search_container">
                    <div class="search">
                        <input id="ctl00_TxtSearchArticles" class="search_field" maxlength="2147483647" name="ctl00$TxtSearchArticles" type="text" />
                        <input id="ctl00_Button1" class="search_button" name="ctl00$Button1" type="submit" value="Go" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="search_advanced">
                        <a href="/search.aspx">Advanced Search</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slogan">
                source Publishing Corporation</div>
        </div>
        <div class="source_links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/books/">Books</a> </li>
                <li><a href="/journals/">Journals</a> </li>
                <li><a href="/about.html">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="banner">
            <img id="ctl00_ImgTitle" alt="Abstract and Applied Analysis" src="../../../images/banners/AAA.banner.jpg" style="border-width: 0px;" /></div>
        <div id="journal_navigation">
            <a id="ctl00_AboutNav" class="journal_nav_links" href="../">About this 
            Journal</a>
            <a id="ctl00_MtsNav" class="journal_nav_links" href="http://mts.source">
            Submit a Manuscript</a>
            <a id="ctl00_TableofContentsNav" class="last_link" href="/journals/aaa/contents.html">
            Table of Contents</a> </div>
        <div id="content">
            <!--left column-->
            <div id="left_column">
                <div class="green_strip">
                    <div class="journal_icon">
                        Journal Menu</div>
                </div>
                <div class="left_column_list">
                    <ul id="ctl00_BltJournalInformation">
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/ai.html">Abstracting and Indexing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/aims.html">Aims and Scope</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/apc.html">Article Processing 
                        Charges</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/aip.html">Articles in Press</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/guidelines.html">Author Guidelines</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/biblio.html">Bibliographic Information</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/contact.html">Contact Information</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/editors.html">Editorial Board</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/workflow.html">Editorial Workflow</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/etoc.html">Free eTOC Alerts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/reviewers.html">Reviewers Acknowledgment</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/subs.html">Subscription Information</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="ctl00_SpecialIssuesDiv" class="special_issues">
                    <ul id="ctl00_BltSpecialIssues">
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/osi.html">Open Special Issues</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/psi.html">Published Special Issues</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/journals/aaa/siguidelines.html">Special Issue 
                        Guidelines</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ad2">
                    <a href="/special.issues.html">Call for Proposals for <br />
                    Special Issues</a></div>
                <!--end left column-->
                <!--middle content--></div>
            <div class="middle_content">
                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CoverDiv" class="right_column">
                    <div class="cover" visible="false">
                        <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_imgDownLoadIssue" class="img_cover" src="/images/si/9775945445.jpg" style="border-width: 0px;" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownloadIssueDiv" class="download_pdf">
                        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownloadIssue" class="download_box" href="/journals/AAA/si/9775945445.pdf">
                        PDF Download (1.7MB)</a> </div>
                </div>
                <h2>Topological and variational methods of nonlinear analysis and 
                their applications</h2>
                <span class="press_info">Guest Editors: V. G. Zvyagin, Yu. E. Gliklikh, 
                V. V. Obukhovskii, A. I. Perov, B. N. Sadovskii, Yu. I. Sapronov, 
                V. A. Sobolev, and Z. B. Tsaliuk</span>
                <ul class="more_articles_ul">
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/093926.abs.html">Topological 
                    and variational methods of nonlinear analysis and their applications</a>, 
                    V. G. Zvyagin, Yu. E. Gliklikh, and V. V. Obukhovskii<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 93926, 2 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/036215.abs.html">The Kolmogorov 
                    equation in the stochastic fragmentation theory and branching 
                    processes with infinite collection of particle types</a>, R. 
                    Ye. Brodskii and Yu. P. Virchenko<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 36215, 10 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/039786.abs.html">Necessary and 
                    sufficient conditions for global-in-time existence of solutions 
                    of ordinary, stochastic, and parabolic differential equations</a>, 
                    Yuri E. Gliklikh<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 39786, 17 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/086173.abs.html">On calculation 
                    of the relative index of a fixed point in the nondegenerate 
                    case</a>, A. V. Guminskaya and P. P. Zabreiko<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 86173, 11 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/082602.abs.html">Theorem on 
                    the union of two topologically flat cells of codimension 1 in <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mml:mrow><mml:msup><mml:mi>
                    ℝ</mml:mi><mml:mi>n</mml:mi></mml:msup></mml:mrow></mml:math></a>, 
                    A. V. Chernavsky<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 82602, 9 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/078928.abs.html">Bourgin-Yang-type 
                    theorem for <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mml:mi>
                    a</mml:mi></mml:math>-compact perturbations of closed operators. 
                    Part I. The case of index theories with dimension property</a>, 
                    Sergey A. Antonyan, Zalman I. Balanov, and Boris D. Gel'man<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 78928, 13 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/048132.abs.html">Gantmacher-Kreĭn 
                    theorem for 2 nonnegative operators in spaces of functions</a>, 
                    O. Y. Kushel and P. P. Zabreiko<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 48132, 15 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/051794.abs.html">An oriented 
                    coincidence index for nonlinear Fredholm inclusions with nonconvex-valued 
                    perturbations</a>, Valeri Obukhovskii, Pietro Zecca, and Victor 
                    Zvyagin<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 51794, 21 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/043560.abs.html">Flow of electrorheological 
                    fluid under conditions of slip on the boundary</a>, R. H. W. 
                    Hoppe, M. Y. Kuzmin, W. G. Litvinov, and V. G. Zvyagin<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 43560, 14 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/056367.abs.html">The integral 
                    limit theorem in the first passage problem for sums of independent 
                    nonnegative lattice variables</a>, Yuri P. Virchenko and M. 
                    I. Yastrubenko<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 56367, 12 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/094509.abs.html">On a certain 
                    functional equation in the algebra of polynomials with complex 
                    coefficients</a>, E. Muhamadiev<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 94509, 15 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/090837.abs.html">The mappings 
                    of degree 1</a>, Maria N. Krein<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 90837, 14 pages</li>
                    <li><a href="/journals/aaa/2006/098081.abs.html">Surgery and 
                    the relative index in elliptic theory</a>, V. E. Nazaikinskii 
                    and B. Yu. Sternin<br />
                    Volume 2006 (2006), Article ID 98081, 16 pages</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--End middle content-->
            <div class="lock">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Copyright © 2009 source Publishing Corporation. All rights reserved.</div>
    <div>
        <input id="__EVENTTARGET" name="__EVENTTARGET" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input id="__EVENTARGUMENT" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input id="__EVENTVALIDATION" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" type="hidden" value="/wEWAwLtoumZCALf45uzBALl97ftDc6OBH/ckFnY/ReuOp8cM4AI4UJ7" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
    <script src="/WebResource.axd?d=MWyuQ-y_HwfuoPD0hR0Hzw2&amp;t=633562784243119689" type="text/javascript"></script>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

This 
is the jquery link

```
<script src="http://beta.source/Scripts/JQInt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Specifically what browsers have you tested it in?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it error? What does the error say? What markup is this trying to manipulate?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is this code supposed to do? What does it do in Safari, Opera, Internet Explorer and what does not work in Firefox?

Comment: Also, this looks like layout manipulation. Any reason why you're not handling this in your CSS?

Comment: Where is your jQuery code - in the page, in an external .js file? Is the jquery source file correctly referenced? What shows up in Firebug when you look at the HTML tab, or go to debug the scripts?

Comment: Have you run the generated markup through a validator? FireFox is generally stricter than the other browsers when there are syntactical errors in the markup, and this can cause any JavaScript code after the error to not be executed.

Answer (score 9):

jQuery is cross-browser compatible. The problem is more likely to be in your code than in the jQuery source, so that would be the first place to look.

The first thing that stands out is the use of browser-detection code. jQuery recommends use of [`$.support`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.support) instead of attempting to tailor code to specific browser versions, as your code will be more flexible going forward.

Secondly, what is the behaviour that you expect to see, what do you see in IE et.al and what do you see in Firefox? Having a clearer picture of your expectations is likely to lead more quickly to the correct answer.

**EDIT:**

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/egegi)** using your code, that works for me in Firefox 3.5.3. Add **/edit** to the URL to see the code. As can be seen, all `<div>` elements are set to be `width 100px`. When the DOM has finished loading, the width of `<div class="download_box">` and `<div class="download_pdf">` is shortened by `22px` in all browsers other than IE.

*jQuery code*

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var marker = $('#browser');
    $.each($.browser, function(i, val) {
      $("<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>")
                .appendTo(marker);
    });

    var h = $(".img_cover").width();

    if ($.browser.msie) {
    $(".download_box").width(h + 1);
    $(".download_pdf").width(h + 1);
    $(".right_column").width(h);
    }
    else{
    $(".download_box").width(h - 22);
    $(".download_pdf").width(h - 22);  
    }
 });
```

*relevant HTML*

```
  <div class="img_cover" style="width:100px;background-color:blue;">.img_cover</div>
  <div class="download_box" style="width:100px;background-color:blue;">.download_box</div>
  <div class="download_pdf" style="width:100px;background-color:blue;">.download_pdf</div>
  <div class="right_column" style="width:100px;background-color:blue;">.right_column</div>
  <br/>
  <div id="browser"></div>
```

Comment: thnx alot,
i tried to make alert(h);
but it didn't work on Firefox ,and worked on Opera,IE...
i think the problem  is firefox didnt see the code inside the 

$(document).ready(function () {

Comment: it will see the code inside $(document).ready() as demonstrated in the example. Can you amend your question post more information about how your page(s)/file(s) are setup. Something like the following- "I have this is in a Master Page - CODE HERE -", "I have this in a separate .js file - CODE HERE", etc, etc.

Comment: At the moment, we can't see where the problem is exactly as in the context of the code that you have posted, everything works as expected.

Comment: i know and it worked  correctly on my local pc but when it attached on the aspx file and uploaded to the server Firefox  didn't respond

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is cross-broswer compatible, as everyone is pointing out, so I'm not going to touch that part of the question. As for you question about the code not working in FF, can you try this:

```
// Note the px.
$(".download_box").width((h - 22) + "px");
$(".download_pdf").width((h - 22) + "px");
```

instead of

```
$(".download_box").width(h - 22);
$(".download_pdf").width(h - 22);
```

Comment: You should use brackets when mixing strings and integers... `((h - 22) + "px")`